# MicroSchart wont allow mvvm binding

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, charts, xamarin.ios

i tried creating a chart in my xamarin ios mvvm app, it works with hardcoded data. when i try setting data from my api it crashes because the my view loads before my data is loaded so it returns `null`.
i did bind it.

error: `Value cannot be null.`

view(in viewdidload):

```
 MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<UserCoinsTableView, UserCoinViewModel> set = new MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<UserCoinsTableView, UserCoinViewModel>(this);

        var control = new MvxUIRefreshControl();
        TableView.AddSubview(control);
        var entries = new[]
         {
            new Entry(1)
            {

            },
            new Entry(1)
            {

            }                
        };

        //var chart = new LineChart() { Entries = entries };
        var chart = new LineChart() { Entries = (this.ViewModel as UserCoinViewModel).Entries };

        var chartView = new ChartView
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(0, 32, this.View.Bounds.Width, 160),
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            Chart = chart
        };

        this.headerView.AddSubview(chartView);
        set.Bind(chart.Entries).To(vm => vm.Entries);
        set.Apply();
```

ViewModel:

```
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        var entries = _CoinHistory.Select(x => new Entry(float.Parse(x.price_btc))).ToArray();

        _entries = entries;
        Entries = _entries;
    }
```

dataprops:

```
    private IEnumerable<Entry> _entries;
    public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries
    {
        get
        {
            return _entries;
        }
        set
        {
            _entries = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Entries);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding expression is wrong. You didn't specify the Target of the binding. Since MvvmCross doesn't have any built in Target Binding declarations for this chart view, it does not know what the target is. I wrote a blog post about this matter which you can find here: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2018/01/mvvmcross-binding-target.html

But the issue here is:

```
set.Bind(chart.Entries)
```

Bind should have the `View` you are trying to bind not the Target. Instead `Entries` should be specified using the `For()` chain method:

```
set.Bind(chart).For(c => c.Entries)
```

Now you've specified the target. Then you can use `To()` to specify the source of the binding.

```
set.Bind(chart).For(c => c.Entries).To(vm => vm.Entries);
```

This will only work if your chart component's `Entries` property is a public property with a public getter and setter.

Comment: Can I change the 'Entries' property, since this is a library I import?

Comment: Not unless you subclass it. It doesn't have a public setter? If so you need to create a custom target binding that can use a method to provide the entries insted.